# Pause/Play button for my breakout-clone on Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, playback, pause

I am trying to code a Pause/Play button for my breakout-clone because I have some text and links planned for the site on which the game will be, so you can pause the game while reading the text or interacting with links. My code is written in JS and mostly consists of "function" and "var". If the CSS or the HTML file is needed for an answer then please contact me. This is my first time asking anything on stackoverflow and I would be glad for any help.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("TheCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var x = canvas.width/2;
var y = canvas.height-50;
var dx = 2
var dy = -2;
var ballRadius = 10;
var paddleHeight = 15;
var paddleWidth = 80;
var paddleX = (canvas.width-paddleWidth) / 2;
var rightPressed = false;
var leftPressed = false;
var brickRowCount = 6;
var brickColumnCount = 4;
var brickWidth = 90;
var brickHeight = 20;
var brickPadding = 10;
var brickOffsetTop = 30;
var brickOffsetLeft = 15;
var score = 0;
var lives = 99;

var bricks = [];
for(var c=0; c<brickColumnCount; c++) {
    bricks[c] = [];
    for(var r=0; r<brickRowCount; r++) {
        bricks[c][r] = { x: 0, y: 0,status: 1 };
    }
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveHandler, false);

function mouseMoveHandler(e) {
    var relativeX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    if(relativeX > 0 && relativeX < canvas.width) {
        paddleX = relativeX - paddleWidth/2;
    }
}

function keyDownHandler(e) {
    if(e.key == "Right" || e.key == "ArrowRight") {
        rightPressed = true;
    }
    else if(e.key === "Left" || e.key == "ArrowLeft") {
        leftPressed = true;
    }
}

function keyUpHandler(e) {
    if(e.key === "Right" || e.key === "ArrowRight") {
        rightPressed = false;
    }
    else if(e.key === "Left" || e.key === "ArrowLeft") {
        leftPressed = false;
    }
}

function collisionDetection() {
    for(var c=0; c<brickColumnCount; c++) {
        for(var r=0; r<brickRowCount; r++) {
            var b = bricks[c][r];
            if(b.status == 1) {
                if(x > b.x && x < b.x+brickWidth && y > b.y && y < b.y+brickHeight) {
                    dy = -dy;
                    b.status = 0;
                    score++;
                    if(score == brickRowCount*brickColumnCount) {
                        alert("YOU WIN, WELL DONE!");
                        document.location.reload();
                        clearInterval(interval); // <- This is needed for the browser to end the game \\
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function drawScore() {
    ctx.font = "16px OCR A";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#00ffd9"
    ctx.fillText("Score: "+score, 8, 20);
}

function drawLives() {
    ctx.font = "16px OCR A"
    ctx.fillStyle = "00ffd9"
    ctx.fillText("Lives: "+lives, canvas.width-85, 20);
}

function drawBall() {
    // drawing code \\
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.lineWidth=3
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#00ff00";
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}
function drawPaddle() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(paddleX, canvas.height-15, paddleWidth, paddleHeight);
    ctx.lineWidth=2
    ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}
function drawBricks() {
    for(var c=0; c<brickColumnCount; c++) {
        for(var r=0; r<brickRowCount; r++) {
            if(bricks[c][r].status == 1) {
                var brickX = (c*(brickWidth+brickPadding))+brickOffsetLeft;
                var brickY = (r*(brickHeight+brickPadding))+brickOffsetTop;
                bricks[c][r].x = brickX;
                bricks[c][r].y = brickY;
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.rect(brickX, brickY, brickWidth, brickHeight);
                ctx.strokeStyle = "#33FFFF";
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.closePath();
            }
        }
    }
}

function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    drawBricks();
    drawBall();
    drawPaddle();
    drawScore();
    drawLives();
    collisionDetection();

    if (x + dx > canvas.width - ballRadius || x + dx < ballRadius) {
        dx = -dx;
    }
    if (y + dy < ballRadius) {
        dy = -dy;
    }
    else if (y + dy > canvas.height - ballRadius) {
        if (x > paddleX && x < paddleX + paddleWidth) {
            dy = -dy;
        }
        else {
            lives--;
            if(!lives) {
                alert("Game Over! Press 'Ok' to reload!");
                document.location.reload();
                clearInterval(interval); // Is needed for Browser to end the game \\
            }
            else {
                x = canvas.width/2;
                y = canvas.height-30
                dx = 2;
                dy = -2;
                paddleX = (canvas.width-paddleWidth)/2;
            }
        }
    }
    if (rightPressed && paddleX < canvas.width - paddleWidth) {
        paddleX += 3;
    } else if (leftPressed && paddleX > 0) {
        paddleX -= 3;
    }
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
}
var interval = setInterval(draw, 9);

var checkbox = document.getElementById('darkmode');

function darkmode() {
    if (checkbox.checked == true){
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--primary-background', 'black');
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--primary-color', 'white');
    } else {
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--primary-background', 'white');
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--primary-color', 'black');
    }
}

checkbox.addEventListener('click', darkmode);

darkmode();
```